# JSX - Difference between onChangeMode and onChangePage

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between onChangeMode and onChangePage?  i was studying a sample react web app code and got confused.  Looks like they both respond to events but i would like to get some more info.

Comment: You should probably show the sample.

Comment: i just read the source code again.  they were props functions like "this.props.onChangeMode('create')" or "this.props.onChangePage(e)". so they were not the official JSX functions at all.    Learning new things every day.  Thank You!